# prevent knitr/Rmarkdown from interleaving chunk output with code

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

When I use knitr to build an HTML document out of the following code:

````
Chunk Output
========================================================

Outside a chunk.

```{r chunk1, results='asis'}

cat('Inside a chunk\n\n')

for (i in 1:3) {
    cat('* Inside loop #', i, '\n')
}

cat('Outside a loop, but still inside the first chunk')
```

Between chunks.

```{r chunk2, results='asis'}

cat('Inside second chunk')

```
````

[I get output](http://rpubs.com/HarlanH/chunktest) where the code in `chunk1` is interleaved with the output of the `cat` statements. Interestingly, the output within the `for` loop is output as a single block.

I would prefer to have all of the *code* from `chunk1` to appear first, followed by all of the *output* from `chunk1`. Is there a way to ask Rmarkdown/knitr to avoid the more granular interweaving that it's currently doing?

Comment: Not quite getting what you want but you could make 2 code chunks that are identical, one where you `eval = FALSE` and the second where you `echo = FALSE`.

Comment: I could do that. Or I can wrap the contents of the chunks in `for (x in 1)`, which keeps Rmarkdown from interleaving the output (at the cost of superfluous code in my doc). But I'd prefer to have an option to do this the right way. Anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: @Harlan I don't think this is easy because of the way knitr processes these blocks. A minimal hack would be to put the block inside `{}`

Comment: @Hadley, that works, although it's obviously not ideal. If you write that as an answer, I'll call it the solution. :)

Comment: Here is [another solution](https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/58233ee63a581847411c), where you use `results = 'hide'` to suppress output and add a dependent chunk with `echo = F, results = "asis"`. You might submit a feature request for an option called `results = "hold"` just like `fig.show = "hold"` which would do this automatically for results, since there seem to be some use cases for this.

Comment: @Ramnath, yes, that works! And doesn't require the extra characters in the code block. I'll submit a feature request to knitr... Thanks! (And please copy this to an answer to collect your reputation points! :) )

Comment: Feature request heard, and code done.

Comment: This is customer service at its very best @Yihui!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the solution I proposed

````
Chunk Output
========================================================

Outside a chunk.

```{r chunk1, results='hide'}

cat('Inside a chunk\n\n')

for (i in 1:3) {
    cat('* Inside loop #', i, '\n')
}

cat('Outside a loop, but still inside the first chunk')
```

```{r ref.label = 'chunk1', results = 'asis', echo = F}

```
````

In the latest version of knitr, @yihui has added a new chunk option `results = "hold"`, which automatically holds printing of all output to the end. Accordingly, we can just write

````
Chunk Output
========================================================

Outside a chunk.

```{r chunk1, results='hold'}

cat('Inside a chunk\n\n')

for (i in 1:3) {
    cat('* Inside loop #', i, '\n')
}

cat('Outside a loop, but still inside the first chunk')
```
````